# MySQL - Join row of one table as a column of another

Tags: mysql

Really hoping someone can help with this. I'm sure there are better ways to structure my data, but due to time constraints it would be ideal to have a solution for the current structure if possible.

I have 2 tables with the following structure:

Table 1

```
id  field1
1   quest1  
2   quest2
3   quest3
```

Table 2

```
id  uid  quest1  quest2  quest3
1   18   yes     no      yes
2   27   yes     no      no
```

Basically, I need to return table 1 with a row of table 2 (based upon uid) in the following format:

```
id  field1  field2
1   quest1  yes
2   quest2  no
3   quest3  yes
```

Is this possible at all? Looking online I keep coming across Pivot Tables and Crosstab Queries, but they don't seem to be able to achieve what I'm after...unless I'm wrong? (which I probably am lol).

Appreciate any help anyone can give for this.

Matt

Comment: It is not clear to me where field2 in your output comes from, and how you are joing on uid when there are no uid values that match id in table1.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. field 2 is in theory one of the rows from table 2 so in essence WHERE uid = '18'. Does this help?

Comment: @eggyal thanks for your solution, however none of the answers actually gave me the outcome I was after, but I think this was down to my explanation of the question rather than peoples understanding of what I was after. However after I looked at what I was trying to do, it seemed to me like I was trying to make a square block fit a round hole, so I decided upon a different approach involving storing the data in separate arrays and using them that way (this whole thing is part of a PHP project using CodeIgniter. Thanks for your answer though, much appreciated as I did actually learn something

Comment: @MattSmith: Did you manage to resolve it some other way?  Perhaps you could post your own answer for others to learn from?  Or if it's still unresolved, you could try editing your question to make clearer what it is that you're after? * **EDIT**: after a quick re-read of your question, I think my modified answer is exactly what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support pivot tables/crosstab queries.

It has been sometimes criticized for that but the defense is that it's a feature, not deficiency :-) Pivot queries belong more to the presentation layer, as what they create is not a table in database sense. So they more belong to the applictation layer that extracts the data from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, CASE t1.field1
  WHEN 'quest1' THEN t2.quest1
  WHEN 'quest2' THEN t2.quest2
  WHEN 'quest3' THEN t2.quest3
END AS field2
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t2.uid = 18;
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea03b/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t2.field1, t2.field2 
from table1 t1
inner join (
    select id, 'quest1' as field1, quest1 as field2 from table2
    union all
    select id, 'quest2' as field1, quest2 as field2 from table2
    union all
    select id, 'quest3' as field1, quest3 as field2 from table2
) t2u on t1.id = t2.id
where t2.uid = 18
```